# How to display something upon page load for a specified amount of time? (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

See this Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/

```
<img class="image" 
src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" 
width="120" height="120">
```

I want an image like that to rotate upon the webpage loading, for a set amount of time (say, 5 seconds).
How can I achieve this using CSS/Javascript?
Please note: I do not want the script to continue running for the 5 seconds, I want it to completely halt until the image has finished spinning.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `setTimeout`  in JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){ 
$('.image').fadeOut("slow"); 
},5000)      //for 5 seconds
})
```

Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/9293/)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.